# How to read "paired data" into an R data.table? Using an R list?

Tags: r, list, dictionary, dataframe, data.table

Let's say I have a `data.table` in R:

```
library("data.table")
DT = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a","a"),v=rnorm(6))

> DT
       x           v
    1: b  0.77399102
    2: b  0.71450334
    3: b  0.07187842
    4: a -0.88098815
    5: a -0.90192891
    6: a  0.66439642
```

I supply a vector for the `x` field, and a vector for the `v` field, each with 6 items.

However, you see that I supply `b` three times, and `a` three times. This is a key-value pair, i.e.

```
'b' : '0.77399102', '0.71450334', '0.07187842'
'a' : '-0.88098815', '-0.90192891', '0.66439642'
```

In R, one would implement this as a list, i.e.

```
pairs = list(b = c('0.77399102', '0.71450334', '0.07187842'), 
             a = c('-0.88098815', '-0.90192891', '0.66439642'))
```

I would like to input the R list `pairs` into a `data.table`. Is this possible? I'm confused how to define the `x` and `v` fields with this object. If this isn't possible, how would one do this?

Comment: What do you want to end up with after inputing the `pairs` into a `data.table`?

Comment: What's wrong with `data.table(pairs = pairs)`? Both `data.frame` and `data.table` support list columns.

Comment: How does your data start? If it's in XML or JSON there are nice packages for parsing it into R objects...

Comment: While the pairs format is more elegant, you will probably find `DT` easier to work with for analysis. List columns are slow and require cumbersome syntax.

Comment: @Frank The reason I ask is because the alternative seems to be to explicitly list these values in a vector, like `x=c("b","b","b","a","a","a")`. I'm bound to make mistakes this way

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that no one mentioned it, but the alternative is: `s = stack(pairs); names(s) <- c("v", "x")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `data.table(x = names(pairs), v = pairs)`.  This also works with `data.frame`.